# How can i clone project from Git Lab in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and i am having a task that i should clone the project from the private repository to remote machine in "Ansible-Playbook".Below is my .yml file for cloning the project,i tried lot of ways i am not able to do it can anyone help in this...

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars: 
    username: <user name>
    password: <paas>
    repo_name: user 

  tasks:
  - name: Ansible Git Module with Username Password.
    git:
     repo: 'https://{{ <user name> | urlencode }}:{{ pass | urlencode }}@gitlab.com/{{ mpsrc }}/{{ be/user }}.git'
     dest: /root/user
```

when i run the above code i am getting error

```
.fatal: [167.71.238.31]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u'@' at 20. String: https://{{<user-name> | urlencode }}:{{ <pass> | urlencode }}@gitlab.com/{{ mpsrc }}/{{ be/user }}.git"}
```

can anyone help me on this error

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior, so you'll need to create a smaller example of that behavior, using `debug: msg:` or similar; also, you didn't include `ansible --version` in order to know if you're on some weird version or platform